# jQuery Toggle only one div with the same class on click and toggle class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle the only div respected to the menu icon and want to keep rest of divs hidden. If any of them is opened than hide them all but the clicked one.

Also, want to toggle `rotate` class on the menu icon so when the respective div is opened it shows rotated and when hidden that it will have a normal state.

I am having trouble achieving the result with below code. Can someone help me to fix this?

**Code:**

```js
$('.more-buttons').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('rotate')) {
      $(this).removeClass('rotate');
    }

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id).toggleClass('rotate');
    $('#' + id).next('.additional-buttons-model').slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="more-buttons" id="551">
  <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="551">
  <div class="view-buttons">
    <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
    <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
    <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you actually nesting `input` tags?

Comment: No, I think it's a sublime formatter did something wrong. Let me clear it.

Comment: @AngelPolitis I have updated code. Thanks a lot..

Comment: You're welcome! I also edited your question and put your code in a snippet so that it can be tested easily

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do with this code ` var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + id).toggleClass('rotate'); ` . `$("#" + id)` will select `$(this)` , in your case, `.more-buttons#551` . Why you select it that way? Also, why you use `each` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing the content of the clicked button you have to hide the other content. I have done that. Check out the code below:

```js
$('.more-buttons').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        var clickbtn = $(this);
        $('.more-buttons').not(clickbtn).each(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('rotate');
        });
        var id = clickbtn.attr('id');
        $('#' + id).toggleClass('rotate');
        var content = $('#' + id).next('.additional-buttons-model');
        $('.additional-buttons-model').not(content).each(function(){
           $(this).css('display','none');
        });
        content.slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more-buttons" id="551">
    <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="551">
    <div class="view-buttons">
        <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
        <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
        <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="more-buttons" id="552">
    <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="552">
    <div class="view-buttons">
        <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
        <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
        <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="more-buttons" id="553">
    <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="553">
    <div class="view-buttons">
        <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
        <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
        <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="more-buttons" id="554">
    <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="554">
    <div class="view-buttons">
        <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
        <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
        <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
    </div>
</div>
```

As per the comment I am adding the following code:

```
$('body').not('.more-buttons').click(function () {
    var clickbtn = $('.more-buttons');
    $(clickbtn).each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('rotate');
    });
});

$('body').not('.additional-buttons-model').click(function () {
    var content = $('.additional-buttons-model');
    $(content).each(function(){
       $(this).css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Add the above code in your script.

Comment: Try clicking on the `button` of the shown `div` multiple times. You won't like it!

Comment: Good! It seems like your edit fixed the issue I mentioned.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Yah, I checked that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know who gave you down vote but only your solution is working for me. Rest of solutions I have tried and get the same issue as I was having. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @CodeLღver I have little more issue. Can you help me to hide all and remove rotate class if clicks on body/html?

Comment: @CodeLover Wait let me understand the issue that you are saying and think about the solution.

Comment: @CodeLover if your this menu content wrap with any other div or class then let me know?

Comment: @CodeLღver well, your code is perfect. But the issue I mean to say that I want to hide `additional-buttons-model` when someone clicks outside. I have tried to do that but then it is showing and hiding when I click on the `more-buttons`

Comment: @CodeLover got your issue. Wait for few minutes I am give you solution.

Comment: @CodeLover Please check the updated answer. I have added the solution as you want in the bottom of answer.

Comment: @CodeLover Happy to help you :)

Comment: @CodeLღver, as to the additional code you provided, `$('body').not('.more-buttons')` and `$('body').not('.additional-buttons-model')` mean the exact same thing, `$('body')`, because the `body` has none of these classes. You might want to edit your code a little bit to make your intention clear 

Comment: @AngelPolitis Perhaps you don't have the knowledge of jQuery. Or intentionally doing that. Tell me how  `$('body').not('.more-buttons')` and `$('body').not('.additional-buttons-model')`  are same. Just give me the answer of this question.

Comment: @CodeLღver I know very well what I'm saying. In `jQuery`, `not()` is used to remove elements from a set of matched elements. In the case of `$("body")`, the only element in the set is the `body`, because an HTML document has only one `body`. Since in the OP's code the `body` has neither of the classes you used in `not()` the result is `$("body")`. So, in this context, they mean the exact same thing. Answer given.

Comment: @CodeLღver we say the same thing. You just used a fancier word. The point is that your code does not have any effect, because `$("body")` only selects the body and the body has none of these classes. Even if it did, your code would still be meaningless as the `jQuery` object would be empty and the `click` event wouldn't be attached at all.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the desired effect you can use the following code:

```
/* Cache the buttons. */
var btns = $('.more-buttons');

/* When a button is clicked... */
btns.on('click', function(e) {
   var
      /* Cache the clicked button. */
      btn = $(this),

      /* Cache the corresponding div. */
      div = btn.next('.additional-buttons-model');

   /* Toggle the 'rotate' class. */
   btn.toggleClass('rotate');

   /* Remove the rotate class from every button except the one clicked. */
   btns.not(btn).removeClass('rotate');

   /* Slide Up all divs but the one following the button. */
   btn.siblings('.additional-buttons-model').not(div).slideUp('fast');

   /* Slide the div following the button. */
   div.slideToggle('fast');

   /* Prevent the propagation of the event to the body. */
   e.stopPropagation();
});

/* When the user clicks on the body of the document... */
$("body").on("click", function () {
   /* Cache the buttons. */
   var btns = $(".more-buttons");

   /* Remove the 'rotate' class from all buttons. */
   btns.removeClass("rotate");

   /* Hide all divs of additional buttons. */
   btns.siblings('.additional-buttons-model').slideUp('fast');
});
```

In simple terms, the above code does three things regarding the `div` elements:

1. First, it slides all `div` elements not following the clicked `button` up.
2. Then, it slides the `div` corresponding to the clicked `button` up or down.
3. When the body is clicked, all `div` elements are slid up and all icons lose the 'rotate' class.

---

**Notes:** *(about your code* *)*

1. Instead of using `each` you can simply say `$('.more-buttons').on('click', ...)` to take advantage of the loop `jQuery` does internally.
2. Instead of using `$(this)` over and over, just cache it once and use the variable. This way, only a single `jQuery` object will be created each time instead of 4.
3. There is no reason to cache and use the id of the clicked button *(at least in the code you provided in the question)*.

---

**Snippet:**

```js
/* Cache the buttons. */
var btns = $('.more-buttons');

/* When a button is clicked... */
btns.on('click', function(e) {
   var
      /* Cache the clicked button. */
      btn = $(this),

      /* Cache the corresponding div. */
      div = btn.next('.additional-buttons-model');

   /* Toggle the 'rotate' class. */
   btn.toggleClass('rotate');

   /* Remove the rotate class from every button except the one clicked. */
   btns.not(btn).removeClass('rotate');

   /* Slide Up all divs but the one following the button. */
   btn.siblings('.additional-buttons-model').not(div).slideUp('fast');

   /* Slide the div following the button. */
   div.slideToggle('fast');

   /* Prevent the propagation of the event to the body. */
   e.stopPropagation();
});

/* When the user clicks on the body of the document... */
$("body").on("click", function () {
   /* Cache the buttons. */
   var btns = $(".more-buttons");

   /* Remove the 'rotate' class from all buttons. */
   btns.removeClass("rotate");

   /* Hide all divs of additional buttons. */
   btns.siblings('.additional-buttons-model').slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
/* Used to allow you to test the click on the body in the snippet. */
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery Script -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="more-buttons" id="551">
  <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="551">
  <div class="view-buttons">
    <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
    <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
    <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="more-buttons" id="552">
  <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="552">
  <div class="view-buttons">
    <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
    <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
    <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="more-buttons" id="553">
  <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
</div>

<div class="additional-buttons-model" data-id="553">
  <div class="view-buttons">
    <input class="light-button" name="doedit" type="submit" value="edit">
    <input class="light-button" name="doclose" type="submit" value="close">
    <input class="light-button" name="dohide" type="submit" value="hide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccg345oz/) demo.

```
$('.more-buttons').on('click', function () {
  if($(this).hasClass('rotate')) {
    return false;
  }

  $(this).parent().find('.additional-buttons-model').slideUp('fast');
  $(this).parent().find('.more-buttons').removeClass('rotate');

  $(this).addClass('rotate');
  $(this).next('.additional-buttons-model').slideDown('fast');
});
```