# jquery toggleClass for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 3 paragraphs and I need to toggle class for each. These 3 paragraphs contain the same class names like below.

```
<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 1</p>

<hr>

<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 2</p>

<hr>

<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 3</p>
```

**The problem**

It will toggle all three items because of the same class name. I came up with an idea to add unique class to 'content' div, but I have to repeat my jquery code to toggle class only each item.

Any help? I need to show content one by one.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yaetrow/)

Comment: Toggle the class based on what? Time, click, keypress?

Comment: it's click event

Comment: _"Here is the fiddle"_ -> [ask] -> Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_

Comment: So, if you click the 3rd "click here" you want to toggle "content 3", not all `.content`?   `$(this).next().toggleClass...`  add code to the question (as per comment above) for a full answer.  Though there's probably a duplicate in SO, problem is finding a relevant one.

Comment: yes, need that way

Comment: Maybe this will help: [/jquery-toggle-only-one-div-with-the-same-class-on-click-and-toggle-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526191/jquery-toggle-only-one-div-with-the-same-class-on-click-and-toggle-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML code the jQuery will indeed target all `.content` elements. So what you want is to target the first element with class `.content`.

You can do that by using the [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function.
Please note that `.content` needs to be a direct sibling of `.news-btn` to make this work.

```js
$(".news-btn").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".content").toggleClass("show-content");
  /* $(this) refers to the element which triggered the event, in this case the .news-btn which is clicked
  .next() will target the next element in line. Note that .content needs to be directly after .news-btn
  toggleClass() speaks for itself */
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.show-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 1</p>

<hr>

<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 2</p>

<hr>

<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 3</p>
```

**Bonus:**

If you only want to show one of the `.content` items, you can use this code. It does basically the same, expect it first hides all `.content` elements, and than adds the class to the first `.content` sibling.

```js
$(".news-btn").click(function() {
  $(".content").removeClass("show-content"); 
  /* hide all .content elements */
  $(this).next().addClass("show-content");
  /* $(this) refers to the element which triggered the event, in this case the .news-btn which is clicked
  .next() will target the next element in line. Note that .content needs to be directly after .news-btn
  addClass() will add the class to the element */
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.show-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 1</p>

<hr>

<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 2</p>

<hr>

<p class="news-btn">Click here</p>
<p class="content">Content 3</p>
```